# How i can execute a function when the ads is closed in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What I want to do exactly is when the user clicks on the button the ad opens and when the user closes the ad he automatically opens the video by executing the function openVideo().

**Library:**

[Link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/admob)

**Button:**

```
<Button onPress={() => this.openAd()}> Play Video <Button>
```

**Code:**

```
_loadInitialState = async () => {

    AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID(INTERSTITIAL_ID);
    AdMobInterstitial.setTestDeviceID(TESTDEVICE_ID);
    await AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync();
    await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync();
}

openVideo(){

    this.video.open();
}

openAd(){

    this._loadInitialState().done();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the doc, it says it is an event called `onAdViewDidDismissScreen()`. I don't know how you implemented the code, but I think you are working with expo, right? Then can you share me the link of the snack project and I can try to help you.

**EDIT1**

Expo Admob lib supports the imperativ API from react native. For listening events, you should create listeners in the componentDidMount method and then destroy them in the componentWillUnmount method.

```
componentDidMount(){
  AdMobInterstitial.addEventListener("event_name", this._functionToCall)
}

componentWillUnmount(){   
  AdMobInterstitial.removeAllListeners();
}
```

You may read the documentation for be sure which events you want to support or listen. Note that iOS and Android have different names for each event, so you should keep that in mind. I just created an Expo Snack based on your example.

[Expo snack link](https://snack.expo.io/@lui5778/expo-admob) or 
[Github Examples](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/blob/master/Example/index.js)

Comment: @bdroid show the code for android. Or did you use teh same code from my Expo snack?